# About the scope in javascript,why the following not output 21 but 22?

Tags: javascript

```
function t()
{
    var x = 1;
    if(true)
    {
        var x = 2;
        alert(x);
    }
    alert(x);
}
t();
```

Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: welcome to javascript :)

Answer (score 6):

Because JavaScript (well ECMAScript) does not have block scope [(yet)](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:block_scoped_bindings). Just function scope.

There's really just one variable declaration that is hoisted to the top of the function, so `x=2` is overwriting the initial value of `1`.

```
function t()
{
    var x = 1;

       // v---------immediately invoked function to create a new scope
    (function() {
          // new variable scope
        if(true)
        {
            var x = 2;
            alert(x); // 2
        }
    })();

    alert(x); // 1
}
t();
```

Comment: Not a very optimistic "yet".  I doubt this will ever change. Imagine the nightmare of  breaking decades(?) of code. EDIT: I stand corrected, your edited link provides some additional insight I did not consider.

Comment: @Anthony: If your code is running in the browser, then very true. Out of the browser in free-standing JS engines, there's reason to be optimistic (or even to enjoy it today). :o)

Answer (score 3):

The 'var' keyword applies within a whole function, so the code you have will behave identically to this:

```
function t() {
    var x = 1;
    if (true) {
        x = 2;
        alert(x);
    }
    alert(x);
}
t();
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Javascript are scoped to the function, not to blocks.  You've got two `var`s, but there's really only one `x`.